# Azure portal: How to measure 6-month retention?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-monitoring

Im using Insights to analyze my user retention, as [described on this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/usage-retention) and it works great to measure retention by days/weeks or up to 3 months.

But how can I get the 6 month retention number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the underlying data retention period is set to a duration longer than 90 days. The maximum retention period is 2 years.

Classic Application Insights resources have a default data retention period of 90 days, you can change that, for example using the portal:

[image]

For workspace based Application Insights resources the data retention period can be set in the Log Analytics Workspace:

[image]

See [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/data-retention-archive?tabs=portal-1%2Cportal-2#configure-the-default-workspace-retention-policy) for more details